# How do I address a period of time in non-time units?

Tags: time, perfect-continuous

I need to say that something has been happening for several bus stops.
What is the most natural way to do it?

Comment: If you want to say something has been occurring for several non-regular intervals of time, the most natural would be whatever the interval marker is. Thus, I would say exactly that: *something has been happening for several bus stops*. For regular intervals, well, anything that is readily converted would work— 1 min = 3000 hummingbird wing beats, say, or 10 billion years = 72 hundredths of the age of the universe.

Comment: When our children were little they found it difficult to understand a certain number of days. Was two and a half days a short or a long time? So we would express it to them in the number of *sleeps* they would have. *Three more sleeps before we go on holiday*. That seemed to provide them with the grasp they needed.

Comment: "*He's been doing that for the last three stops; It's annoying. I wish **he** would stop.*"

Answer (score 4):

Normally we'd say

**The passenger in the red hat boarded the bus three stops back.**

or

**I'm getting off in three more stops.**

or

**The bus has been shaking weirdly for a few stops.**

We wouldn't include the word "bus".